# Cut and replace in javascript string

Tags: javascript, string, replace, split, cut

I got the following string:

```
"14-10-2013 03:04"
```

And I would like a function which replaces the part where the '10' is now, with the part where the '14' is now. How can I do so? I know there is something like split but I'm not too experienced with it.

So far:

```
var string = '14-10-2013 03:04';
var firstPart = string.split("-", 1);
alert(firstPart);
```

But I don't know how to get the second part (the '10') in a variable.

Comment: show us your attempt. And what's your expected output?

Comment: Updated the main post.

Answer (score 2):

For the particular string format (converting `"xx-yy-..."` to `"yy-xx-..."`), a simple replace will do:

```
"14-10-2013 03:04".replace(/(\d\d)-(\d\d)/,"$2-$1")
```

Explanation:

The regular expression `/(\d\d)-(\d\d)/` matches two digits, followed by a dash, followed by two more digits.  The parentheses denote capture groups which can be referenced in the second argument.  In this case, for the string "14-10-2013 03:04", the substring "14-10" matches the regular expression and the two captured texts are "14" and "10".

In the second argument, use `$1`, `$2`, ... to specify where the captured text should be inserted.  In this case, `"$2-$1"` will write the second captured text (14), followed by a dash, followed by the first captured text (10).

For more information, see the [MDN Documentation on String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example%3a_Switching_words_in_a_string).

Comment: @Nirk can you edit your answer and give little explanation on the regular expressions you used. That can be helpful for others who are beginners (like me :)) and if they are referring to this question in future for similar kind of problem

Comment: @UDB I edited my answer.  Let me know if something is unclear

Comment: @Nirk thanks for edit and explanation, the solution is more clear now to me.